# Python: Writing and printing to CSV a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a vector of dates of size 10 and type numpy.ndarray. I also have an array of temperatures at each hour of size 10x24.

I want to print the dates in column A and the corresponding temperature in columns B through Y for rows 1 though 10 in a csv file.

My arrays look as following:

```
print(AllDays)
[datetime.date(2008, 12, 31) datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)
 datetime.date(2009, 1, 2) ..., datetime.date(2015, 11, 28)
 datetime.date(2015, 11, 29) datetime.date(2015, 11, 30)]
```

So far I have to trying to implement this using dataframes as below:

```
TempDay   =   pd.DataFrame()
TempDay['Dates']  =   AllDays #of size 10
TempDay['Temperature'] = TemperatureArray #of size 10x24
```

If the previous step had worked I aimed at:
    TempDay.to_csv('C:\MyFile.csv')

But the above method has not been working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you trying to assign dataframe to column. You could construct pandas dataframe with your `TemperatureArray` and then add `Dates` column:

```
TempDay = pd.DataFrame(TemperatureArray)
TempDay['Dates'] = AllDays
TempDay.to_csv('C:\MyFile.csv')
```